# Transition effect when showing a custom widget in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, widget, effects, transition

I would like to progressively show a custom widget, something like beginning with 0 opacity and going to 100 in a given time. Is it possible to do it in a easy Qt way developed for this purpose? Or may I do it by myself?

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` with `QPropertyAnimation`, which was made exactly for stuff like this. All you need to do is to attach your `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` to your `QWidget` descendant then set it up as the target for a newly created `QPropertyAnimation` and run `QPropertyAnimation` with your desired options!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use a timer which will gradually adjust the opacity of your widget on show events. Take this example (written in a hurry) :

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent){
       //setup the timer first
       timer.setInterval(xxx);
       connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeOut()),this, SLOT(increaseOpacity()));
    };

protected:
    virtual void MyWidget::showEvent ( QShowEvent * event ){
        opacity = 0;
        setOpacity(opacity);
        QWidget::showEvent(event);
        timer.start();
    }

    virtual void MyWidget::hideEvent ( QHideEvent * event ){
        QWidget::hideEvent(event);
        timer.stop();
    }

private slot:
    void increaseOpacity(){
        if(opacity>=1.0){
           timer.stop();
        }
        opacity += 0.1;
        setOpacity(opacity);
    }
private:
   Qtimer timer;
   double opacity;
```

}

Comment: It is not setOpacity method. This method sets opacity only for window, and called another.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: In you example you use setOpacity method. This method is not exist. You gave  url with inforamtion about setWindowOpacity, not about setOpacity. It mean, that you example will have compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

If you QWidget is window you can just use:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.show();

    QPropertyAnimation animation(&w, "windowOpacity");
    animation.setDuration(10000);
    animation.setStartValue(1.0);
    animation.setEndValue(0.0);

    animation.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Else:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QPushButton b(&w);
    w.show();

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect effect;
    b.setGraphicsEffect(&effect);

    QPropertyAnimation animation(&effect, "opacity");
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setStartValue(1.0);
    animation.setEndValue(0.0);

    animation.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Best easy way is use QML for this target:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"

        NumberAnimation on opacity {
            from: 1.0; to: 0.0
            duration: 5000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Second case, I'm trying to animate a button. It does not work. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DídacPérez Before my answer, i had compiled all cases. What is you problem with second cases?

Comment: Hi Milovidov. Simply it does not work, nothing happens once I run the lines above :-( I'm using Qt 4.8.4 on Windows 7 6 bits.

Comment: @DídacPérez Did you had any compile errors? To tell you the truth i had compiled on Qt5.0.0, but i think that on Qt 4.8.4 must work also.